# Перенос сайта с ДЕНВЕРА на хостинг в Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, php, codeigniter

Ребята помогите пожалуста, у меня небольшой сайт написал в `codeigniter` с базой данных. Перенес файлы из денвера в хост, выводит:

> "Internal Server Error"

на локальном сервере все работало.

Comment: какие ошибки в лог пишет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Отчего возникает ошибка 500 (Internal Server Error)](http://www.jino.ru/support/faq/problems/error-500.html#error-500)

Наиболее частой причиной ошибки *500 (Internal Server Error*, внутренняя ошибка сервера) является неверный синтаксис файла `.htaccess` или наличие в нем неподдерживаемых директив. Чаще всего достаточно закомментировать директиву *Options* (для этого нужно поставить в начале строки решетку — `#`), и проблема исчезнет.

Ошибка 500 также может возникать вследствие неправильного обращения с *CGI*-скриптами:

- *CGI*-скрипты должны иметь окончания строк в формате *UNIX* (`\n`), а не в формате *Windows* (`\r\n`). Для этого их надо загружать на сервер по *FTP* в режиме *ASCII*.
- *CGI*-скрипты и папки, в которых они находятся, должны быть доступны для записи только владельцу, то есть иметь права 0755 (`drwxr-xr-x`).
- В результате работы *CGI*-скрипта сформированы неправильные *HTTP*-заголовки ответа. В этом случае для решения проблемы полезно обратиться к `error_log` (его можно найти в контрольной панели в разделе «Хостинг / Статитистика / Лог-файлы / Ошибки»).

Comment: сработало, неправильно написана было '.htaccess'